# docker-compose run multiple commands for a krakend

Tags: docker, docker-compose, krakend

how can run multiple commands for. I try to run `krakend` and export the `openapi` document.

```
version: "3"
services:
  krakend_ce:
    image: devopsfaith/krakend:watch
    volumes:
      - ./krakend:/etc/krakend
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    command: ["run", "-d", "-c", "/etc/krakend/krakend.json"]
    # how to run krakend openapi export -h
```

i want to `krakend openapi export -h`after container is started

Answer (score 1):

Judging by their Dockerfile [from here](https://hub.docker.com/layers/devopsfaith/krakend/watch/images/sha256-2c94c2c8662842162abb1ae0530be990bb1ada58e82784cd92cfc72290d86ca8?context=explore), they set `ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]` and `CMD ["krakend" "run" "-c" "/etc/krakend/krakend.json"]`.

What you need to do, is:

1. Set entrypoint to `/bin/bash`.
2. Create a new bash file to run multiple commands. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
/entrypoint.sh krakend run -c /etc/krakend/krakend.json
# I'm not sure if it runs in foreground or background. For background you can use nohup:
#nohup /entrypoint.sh krakend run -c /etc/krakend/krakend.json &
/entrypoint.sh krakend openapi export -h
```

3. Map the file into the container.
4. Set `cmd` to use the new file.

I'd build a custom Docker image for that, but setting it in docker-compose.yml is also feasible.

```
version: "3"
services:
  krakend_ce:
    image: devopsfaith/krakend:watch
    volumes:
      - ./krakend:/etc/krakend
      - ./your-custom-file.sh:/path/to/your/file.sh
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command: /path/to/your/file.sh
```

Comment: i must chang `/bin/bash` to `/bin/sh` because of failures and got unknow command krakend. I think because the `openapi export` is just for entreprise users

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `watch` tag to run multiple commands, since it monitors the config files for changes, and restart the service.

If you use any other version (than watch), you can run an `sh -c 'your commands; command2'` command without problems.